# Method Illuminate\Support\Str::of does not exist

Tags: laravel

I want to get data from API. But when I put the code below.

```
public function FUNCTION_NAME()
{
    $data['title']='Title';
    $data= Http::get('API_LINK')->json();
    return view('user.PAGENAME', $data);
}
```

Then showing Method Illuminate\Support\Str::of does not exist.
How solved that

Comment: you should send an array as second parameter in : return view(....

Answer (score 1):

It may happen while upgrading laravel framework version of your project. Try clearing application cache, update composer, or `queue:restart` if it is used.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having doesn't seem to relate to the snippet you have provided.

It is complaining that the laravel sting helper `Str` does not have an `of()` method available.

You can find all of the available methods for this class in the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers